# how to open attached document from outlook using java?

Tags: java, outlook

is it possible to open attached document from outlook using java?

Every hour i receive email with text file attached.
i have to open and extract some data from this text file and store it into another text file.

So what i'm doing is to open the email, then right-click and save the attached file for extracting data it's ok.

How could i do it fastly?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you receive your mails using IMAP, then you could write a Java application and use [JavaMail](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/index.html) to connect to the IMAP server, get the mail, and extract data from the attachments.

Comment: is there any other language i could use to read the excel file?*

Answer (score 1):

You can conntect to Outlook with a COM-wrapper. There are libraries like COM4j. You can access the email, extract the data. But IMAP is much simpler.